# Sort dataframe by another on one column - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Let's say i have to data-frames, as shown below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,3,2],'b':[1,2,3,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[34,56,7,55]})
```

I would like to sort `df` data by the order `df2` data on `'a'` column, so the `df.a` column would be the order of `df2.a` and that which makes the whole data-frame that order.

Desired output:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  4
2  3  3
3  4  2
```

(made it manually, and if there's any mistake with it, please tell me :D)

My own attempt:

```
df = df.set_index('a')
df = df.reindex(index=df2['a'])
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Works as expected!!!,

But when i have longer data-frames, like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,5,6],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,4,5],'b':[1,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,4,3]})
```

It doesn't work ass expected.

Note: i don't only want a explanation of why but i also need a solution to do it for big data-frames

Comment: @coldspeed Edited mine, will test.

Comment: @coldspeed Sorry, there's an error `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`, on the `np.searchsorted` one. my version is 0.19.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is create helper columns in both `DataFrame`s, because duplicated values:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('a').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('a').cumcount()

df = df.set_index(['a','g']).reindex(index=df2.set_index(['a','g']).index)
print(df)
       b
a g     
1 0  1.0
2 0  4.0
3 0  3.0
4 0  2.0
3 1  5.0
4 1  5.0
5 0  5.0
6 0  7.0
4 2  NaN
5 1  6.0
```

Or maybe need `merge`:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2[['a','g']], on=['a','g'])
print(df3)
   a  b  g
0  1  1  0
1  4  2  0
2  3  3  0
3  2  4  0
4  3  5  1
5  4  5  1
6  5  5  0
7  5  6  1
8  6  7  0
```